# Como realizar submit de select list da view para o Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Possuo o seguinte código na minha view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DataAniv", "Mailing", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Selecione o mês:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option value="Janeiro">Janeiro</option>
            <option value="Fevereiro">Fevereiro</option>
            <option value="Março">Março</option>
            <option value="Abril">Abril</option>
            <option value="Maio">Maio</option>
            <option value="Junho">Junho</option>
            <option value="Julho">Julho</option>
            <option value="Agosto">Agosto</option>
            <option value="Setembro">Setembro</option>
            <option value="Outubro">Outubro</option>
            <option value="Novembro">Novembro</option>
            <option value="Dezembro">Dezembro</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Gerar">
}
```

A ideia é que assim que o usuário fizer uma seleção nesta list, o "value" seja enviado para o controller que executará uma lógica. Porém, não importa de qual maneira eu tente, o form sempre dá o submit com valor nulo.
Existe possibilidade de o código funcionar desta maneira? Ou obrigatoriamente devo usar Javascript ou @Html.DropdownListFor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para receber o valor do seu select na Controller, você precisa declarar o atributo name. O atributo id tem utilidade "apenas" para o javascript e css, se o input não tiver um name definido ele não será incluído no FormData a ser postado para o servidor.

`<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$("#forumlario").on('submit', function() {

  var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);

  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log('Input:"'+ pair[0] + '", Valor "' + pair[1]+"'");
  }

  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="forumlario">
  <input type="text" id="Campo1" name="CampoName" value="campo com name" />  
  <input type="text" id="Campo3" value="campo sem name" />
  <br>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">
            <option value="Janeiro">Janeiro</option>
            <option value="Fevereiro">Fevereiro</option>
            <option value="Março">Março</option>
            <option value="Abril">Abril</option>
            <option value="Maio">Maio</option>
            <option value="Junho">Junho</option>
            <option value="Julho">Julho</option>
            <option value="Agosto">Agosto</option>
            <option value="Setembro">Setembro</option>
            <option value="Outubro">Outubro</option>
            <option value="Novembro">Novembro</option>
            <option value="Dezembro">Dezembro</option>
        </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Então, na verdade, quando tento enviar para o controller uma tag <input type="text"> eu consigo. O problema é com a tag <select> em específico, não consigo capturar o valor selecionado para enviar para o controller...

Comment: Veja que eu adicionei o seu Select no exemplo, se você não está recebendo o valor de `sel1` e sua `Controller` é porque o tipo dele não está batendo, o atributo espera uma `string` com o nome do mês ou um `int` com um id?

Comment: @NugoSunes, ficou alguma dúvida?

Comment: Desculpe, acabei ficando sem tempo para testar a implementação! Agora que pude fazê-lo era isso mesmo, faltava o atributo name! Muito obrigado.